# Example of loop using pointers rewritten using an STL algorithm, without a loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, stl, for-loop

How would I rewrite the code below for example, using an STL algorithm without a loop?

```
vector<double> pizzaBox;
int biggestSlice = 0;
for (int* p = &pizzaBox[0]; p != pizzaBox[pizzaBox.size()]; p++) {
    if(*p > biggestSlice)
        biggestSlice = *p;
}
```

Comment: This particular algorithm, or any loop in general?

Comment: You should iterate the vector, not the underlying array: `for (vector<double>::iterator p = pizzaBox.begin(); p != pizzaBox.end(); ++p)`. That will work for any kind of container (list, map, hash_map), not just vector. What you do is kind-of guaranteed to work (because vector is required to store the elements in continuous block of memory), but formally undefined.

Comment: Note: `pizzaBox[pizzaBox.size()]` is actually undefined behavior. You are accessing an element beyond the end of the array. If you use `pizzaBox.at(pizzaBox.size())` it will throw an exception.

Comment: Your middle condition is missing an address-of (`&`) operator after the `!=`.  But it should be done using iterators anyway, as Jan Hudec suggests.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you actually meant `vector<int>`, and after correcting your loop end condition, you can use the [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm here:

```
int biggestSlice = *max_element(pizzaBox.begin(), pizzaBox.end());
```

(Notice that `max_element` returns an *iterator*, hence I’m dereferencing the return value before assigning to `biggestSlice`.)

This of course no longer works (= yields undefined behaviour) when the vector is empty. You need to test for this explicitly *before* dereferencing the return value of the function.

Comment: `if (!pizzaBox.empty())`, but then the questioner's code has the same problem.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The OP question has that problem even with a non empty vector.

Comment: @Steve, @Konrad: Note, that it's the dereference that has problem; the `max_element` will happily work on empty collection, returning end.